# JavaScript: Function return is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js. I created a funtion called locationToAddress, but it always returns undefined. This is the code simplified:

```
var lat = '-34.491093';
var long = '-58.558597';

console.log(locationToAddress(lat, long));

function locationToAddress(lat, long) {
  var preUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=';
  var apiKey = '<API_KEY>';

  var url = preUrl + lat + ',' + long + apiKey;

  var addressString = '';

  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      try {
          var jsonLocationObject = JSON.parse(body);
          addressString = JSON.stringify(jsonLocationObject.results[0].formatted_address);
          addressString = addressString.replace(/["]/g, '');
          console.log(addressString);
          return addressString;
        } catch (e) {
          return 'Could not find address';
        }
  });
 }
```

In the console, This code should be seen as:

```
<FORMATTED_ADDRESS>
<FORMATTED_ADDRESS>
```

But I see:

```
undefined
<FORMATTED_ADDRESS>
```

I know the error is in the return of the value as it works perfectly if I call the function without logging the return.

Comment: As you can see by the order of the output, the function returns *before* the response was received. `request` is asynchronous. *Returning* a value is always synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `locationToAddress` doesn't return anything. The `return addressString;` and `return 'Could not find address';` aren't "part" of locationToAddress.

Because the request in the `locationToAddress` is asynchronous I bet you wanted to use the function with a different signature:

```
function locationToAddress(lat, long, callback) { // see the param 'callback'
```

Then in the  `request(url, function (error, response, body) {` you will not use `return` but instead `callback(null, addressString)` and `callback('Could not find address')`. The 1st argument in the `callback` is always error and succinct ones are the data you would like to return.

Beware that in NodeJS most of the code is asynchronous and you have to handle it as such. To kind of make your code look synchronous have a look at [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). The function I use all the times are `series`, `waterfall` and `autoInject`.

*** Complete rewrite with a callback ***

```
function locationToAddress(lat, long, callback) {  // <--- CHANGE
  var preUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=';
  var apiKey = '<API_KEY>';

  var url = preUrl + lat + ',' + long + apiKey;

  var addressString = '';

  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      try {
          var jsonLocationObject = JSON.parse(body);
          addressString = JSON.stringify(jsonLocationObject.results[0].formatted_address);
          addressString = addressString.replace(/["]/g, '');
          console.log(addressString);
          return callback(null, addressString); // CHANGE - null represents "no error"
        } catch (e) {
          return callback('Could not find address'); // CHANGE - nonnull 1st param means an error occured
        }
  });
 }
```

Comment: It does, the line "return addressString" does that.

Comment: @PaulBentley — That line is not part of the `locationToAddress` function.

Comment: @PaulBentley: That line is inside the function you pass to `request`, not in `locationToAddress`. `return` statements don't cross function boundaries. Here is a simplified example: `function foo() { function bar() { return 42; }; bar(); return 21; };` What do you think `foo` returns?

Comment: How would I call the function using callback instead of return and how do I retrieve the result?

Comment: @PaulBentley, I have added the code with the callback.